# Generic way to overwrite a single field type in flow object type

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Given a type

```
type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number,
|};
```

I'd like to be able to map any of its fields to another type. For example,

```
type Y = {|
  a: string,
  b: number,
|};
```

or

```
type Y = {|
  a: number,
  b: any,
|};
```

---

I tried the following:

```
type Overwrite<O: Object, K: $Keys<O>, T> =
  {...O, [K]: T}

type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number,
|};
type Y = Overwrite<X, 'a', string>;

const y: Y = {
  a: '12',
  b: 12,
}
```

at first glance it seemed to work, but then I realized that it also let `b` be overwritten as well, and `a` could be still be `number`

```
const y: Y = {
  a: 1,
  b: '1',
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override using object spread and exact types:

```
type Overwrite<O, T> =
  {...O, ...T}

type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number,
|};
type Y = Overwrite<X, {| a: string |}>;

const y: Y = {
  a: '12',
  b: 12,
}

// $ExpectError
const z: Y = {
  a: 1,
  b: '1',
}
```

Comment: Seems like I was over complicating things because I started working on this problem without the third generic parameter. Thanks.

Comment: offtopic, but what do the | do in your example? ala type X = {| <-- that.. what does that pipe mean/do?

Comment: They represent [exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types)